# What does the exclamation mark in the import mean?

Tags: c#, import, nuget

I have added a nuget package and now I'm trying to add `using` directive but namespace has a yellow exclamtion mark and after adding it I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Emgu' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: maybe a wrong framework version 4.0 -> 4.5

Comment: @Roland changing framewrok version from 4.6 to 4.5.2 solved the problem. Thanks a lot. You may add it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework version of the project is wrong (too low).